# Increment variable value in function bash

Tags: bash

So I can almost guarantee this is a dumb question but I just can't figure this out. I'm trying to count how many times I've indexed files. I need to increment a counter every time I find a pdf file that matches certain criteria (it's metadata must contain 3 specific values). The variable in question is indexCount and I've marked the line where I'm trying to increment it with #NOT SURE ABOUT THIS LINE

```
index() {
    for file in *
    do
        [ -d "$file" ] && (cd "$file"; index)
        oldPath=$(pwd)
        if [ "$( echo "$file" | grep -E '.*\.pdf' )" ]; then
            metadata="$(pdftk "$file" dump_data)"

            echo "$metadata" | $(grep -e '^InfoKey: Title' >/dev/null 2>&1) && echo "$metadata" | $(grep -e '^InfoKey: Author' >/dev/null 2>&1) && echo "$metadata" | $(grep -e '^InfoKey: CreationDate' >/dev/null 2>&1)
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                path="$(pwd)/""$file"
                title=$(getAttr "$metadata" '^InfoKey: Title')
                author=$(getAttr "$metadata" '^InfoKey: Author')
                creation=$(getAttr "$metadata" '^InfoKey: CreationDate')

                authorsArray=($(getAuthors "$author"))

                for auth in "${authorsArray[@]}";
                do
                    createFolders "$auth" "$creation" "$title" "$path" "$oldPath"
                done

                $1=$(($1+1)) #NOT SURE ABOUT THIS LINE
            fi
        fi
    done

    echo $1
}

indexCount=0
index $indexCount
```

Comment: It would be less trouble if you gave a test case that _only_ covered incrementing, as opposed to a test case with a bunch of other code (which may or may not work correctly) mixed in as well. (There's a good answer given for the increment problem, but all the other stuff being mixed into the problem makes it harder to discuss its correctness).

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax is:

```
var=$((var+1))
```

So instead of

```
$1=$(($1+1))
```

you should use a variable name plus the syntax I indicate above. In general, remember bash variables are set without the `$` and used with it.

Quoting from Charles Duffy:

If targeting bash as opposed to POSIX sh, there's also the option of `(( ++var ))` or `(( var += 1 ))`

Comment: Ok so I replaced $1=$(($1+1)) with indexCount=$((indexCount+1) and echo $1 with echo $indexCount. But now it prints 5 1 0 with my test data. I need it to print 6. How do I go about this?

Comment: I don't know where these values come from, but make sure you increment properly by printing `indexCount` every time you loop through your files. Then we will see what can be wrong. Also, see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html

Comment: The values I just listed correspond to the files that met the requirements I mentioned in my post. So it's incrementing indexCount everytime it reaches it however it appears that every time it calls index when recursing through the folders it resets the value of indexCount despite it being global.

Comment: I am guessing that the value is being incremented in a sub-shell every time. I would wrap the `echo $metadadta | ...` into a variable and then check the result of `$?`, so that you do not have those subshells.

Comment: If targeting bash as opposed to POSIX sh, there's also the option of `(( ++var ))` or `(( var += 1 ))`